# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'GeoPoint'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, geofirestore

I want to get current user location on google maps by detected phone device. I was declare my position as geopoint in my model class to get the coordinate map from google maps. so i was confuse either I need to declare my position as geopoint or type of string.

My model task.

```
class Task {
  final String noAduan;
  final String sumberAduan;
  final String kategori;
  List<String> imageUrls = <String>[];
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final String verified;
  final String email;
  final String uid;
  final String id;
  final String address;
  final GeoPoint position;



  Task({this.address, this.position, this.id, this.noAduan, this.sumberAduan, this.kategori, this.imageUrls, this.dateTime, this.verified, this.email, this.uid});

  Task.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : noAduan = data['noAduan'],
        kategori = data['kategori'],
        sumberAduan = data['sumberAduan'],
        dateTime = data['date'],
        verified = data['verified'],
        email = data['email'],
        uid = data['uid'],
        imageUrls = data['urls'],
        id = data['id'],
        address = data['address'],
        position = data['position'];

    Map<String,dynamic> toJson(){
    return{
      'noAduan' : noAduan,
      'kategori' : kategori,
      'sumberAduan' : sumberAduan,
      'date' : dateTime,
      'verified': verified,
      'email': email,
      'uid': uid,
      'url':imageUrls,
      'id':id,
      'address': address,
      'position': position,
    };
  }
}
```

Database service class

```
Future updateLocation(GeoFirePoint point, String address)  async {

      return addTaskCollection.document(id).updateData({
        'position': point.data,
        'address': address,
      }).whenComplete(() {
        print("Update success!");
      });
    }
```

google maps class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fyp/model/Task.dart';
import 'package:fyp/service/database.dart';

import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart' as geoCo;
class GoogleMaps extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleMapsState createState() => _GoogleMapsState();
}

class _GoogleMapsState extends State<GoogleMaps> {

  StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;
  GoogleMapController googleMapController;
  Location _locationTracker = new Location();
  Marker marker;
  Circle circle;
  String addressLocation;
  Task task;
  static final CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(4.2105, 101.9758),
    zoom: 15.00,
  );

  void updateMarker(LocationData newLocalData ) {
    LatLng latLng = LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude);
    this.setState(() {
      marker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("Im here"),
        position: latLng,
        draggable: false,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueCyan),);
    });
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      var location = await _locationTracker.getLocation();
      final coordinated = new geoCo.Coordinates(location.latitude, location.longitude);
      GeoFirePoint point  = GeoFirePoint(location.latitude, location.longitude);
      var address = await geoCo.Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinated);
      var firstAddress = address.first;
      addressLocation = firstAddress.addressLine;
        task = Task(
          address: addressLocation,
          position: point.data //in this line show the error//
        );
        await DatabaseService().updateLocation(point, addressLocation);

      if (_streamSubscription != null) {
        _streamSubscription.cancel();
      }
      _streamSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged.listen((newLocalData) {
        if (googleMapController != null) {
          googleMapController.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
                  bearing: 192.83,
                  target: LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
                  tilt: 0,
                  zoom: 10.00)));
          updateMarker(newLocalData);
        }
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if(e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        debugPrint("Permission Denied");
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  void dispose(){
    if (_streamSubscription != null){
      _streamSubscription.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Google Maps"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
        markers: Set.of((marker!= null) ? [marker] : []),
        circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle] : []),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
          googleMapController = controller;
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
        onPressed: (){
          getCurrentLocation(); //this one also show the error//
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I got an Exception like this:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'GeoPoint'
E/flutter (10865): #0      _GoogleMapsState.getCurrentLocation (package:fyp/maps/google_maps_address.dart:51:27)
E/flutter (10865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10865): #1      _GoogleMapsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:fyp/maps/google_maps_address.dart:102:11)
```

Is there anything that I missing or I make the mistake on my initialize of geofire? someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too, and the geopoint is actually created as a a subset of position - check your database.

I have
[image: screenshot]

and so, you need to call

```
position: data['position']['geopoint']
```

not

```
position: data['position']
```